# How to access the apache container of a task on AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I am setting up an infrastructure to deploy my application on AWS. I am using ECS service because I am trying to deploy a Docker-based application. So far I have created a task definition with two containers one for the apache and another one for PHP. Then I launched an ECS cluster with an EC2 instance and a task running. They all seem to be up and running. Now, I am trying to figure out how I can access the apache of my EC2 instance with the Cluster on the browser.

This is how I created the apache container.

[image]

[image]

And then I created the php container as follow.

[image]

Then I launched an EC2 based ECS cluster with one instance in it. Then I run one task within the cluster. Then I tried to open the public IP address of my instance. It just keeps loading loading and loading. What is wrong with my configuration? How can I access it on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there's a couple of possible scenarios here you could check:

- If do you reach the service and are stuck on an endless reloading loop, which might point to something in your code that could be causing it to do that,
- If you're having a long wait time till the browser actually gives a timeout, which might be caused by not having the right port open on the Security Group associated with your task definition.